# How to remove oxidation on USB connectors?

Tags: usb, connector

I have quite a few USB connectors which have oxidized quite badly. Is there any easy way I can remove the oxidation myself?

[image: IMG:]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Separately, I'm also curious whether I can DIY the gold plating of these connectors without complex/expensive equipment.

Note that I'm doing it for aesthetics/OCD only, not for functionality.

Comment: http://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/redox/definitions.html

Answer (score 1):

You either need isopropyl alcohol (purer the better but 'medical' 70% pure is ok here) for cleaning dirt *or* contact cleaner (for the contacts).

For the plastic parts iso is better/safer. For metal parts, the contact cleaner will remove corrosion *and* slow down/prevent further corrosion. Its not *magic* - actually badly corroded connectors will likely re-corrode after some time, but its safer for mild corrosion, and is *meant* for cleaning and protecting electrical contacts.

Answer (score 0):

For electrical contact cleaning - white vinegar is a good solution (need clean up after applying it), if you have physical access to contacts then a pencil with red eraser (with abrasive) do it job well especially on gold plated contacts (but actually it hard to do with USB sockets), but if it really for…

> “…for aesthetics/OCD only, not for functionality…”

…then you can get on eBay bunch of such connectors and glue them in a socket as a nice, fake USB, or replace them with original ones that match your model, this way it would aesthetics and functional.

Answer (score 0):

If it is oxidation, plain vinegar works best.

If it is just hardened dirt build up (such as the ring dried water leaves), then you can use rubbing alcohol.

If you need to get into the port, you can use things like Q-Tips and pipe cleaners.

Do not use abrasives on the connectors themselves. This can lead to reduced lifespan or bad connectors. Abrasives are fine on connector housing, just not the connector itself.